# Adding a Cron job to a block in moodle

Tags: moodle

I am trying to add a cron job in moodle block.

I am following this tutorial on moodle 3.0 https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks#Responding_to_Cron

When I run /admin/cron.php, my cron job does not execute.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old way uses cron like this:

`/blocks/yourblockname/block_yourblockname.php`

```
class block_yourblockname extends block_base {
    ...
    public function cron() {
        // Your code.
    }
```

and in `/blocks/yourblockname/version.php`

```
$plugin->cron = xxxx; // Cron interval in seconds. 0 means no cron.
```

The new way is to use scheduled tasks - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Task_API

UPDATE: As mentioned by @Developer

If you change the cron value or add a new task then you will also need to increment the version number

```
$plugin->version = xxxx;
```

Comment: Thanks Russell, Can Task API also be used for block type plugin? I put the code in block type plugin but it is not working either.

https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/MOODLE_30_STABLE/blocks/recent_activity/block_recent_activity.php
this has a cron function in it which runs fine when I run /admin/cron.php
wondering why built in is working fine and mine one is not?

Comment: Got it :) One stupid thing which I was missing, I had to reinstall the plugin after doing changes, both old way and new(Task API) are working now. Thanks for your help